# Apache Mahout Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: windows, apache, hadoop, environment-variables, mahout

I have installed Hadoop on windows using Hortonworks. I then downloaded mahout and successfully ran:

`.HADOOP_HOME\bin\hadoop jar C:\mahout-distribution-0.7\mahout-core-0.7-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -s SIMILARITY_COOCURRENCE --input i --output o`

However, that is one of the only modules that works.

When I ran other such as:

`.HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar C:\mahout-distribution-0.72\mahout-core-0.7-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.OnlineLogisticRegression --input u --output u`

I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.OnlineLogisticRegression.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:150)
```

I set my environment variable `MAHOUT_HOME` the my mahout install folder. Anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Are you sure mahout-core-0.7-job.jar contains your OnlineLogisticRegression class?

Comment: I think it does.. or at least the following path exists: C:\mahout-distribution-0.7\core\src\main\java\org\apache\mahout\classifier\sgd\OnlineLogisticRegression.java

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try running the `org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.RunLogistic` from the `mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! But why would mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar work  and not mahout-core-0.7-job.jar? I need to run some of the algorithms in the core one..